# Objective C associated objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, associative-array

Can anyone explain how associated objects work, under the hood?  In particular, does their existence require every object to hold an extra ivar?  Or does Objective C have a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated objects are kept in a dictionary separate from the instance storage.

Comment: One implication of this is that accessing them requires taking a lock. Curiously, retain counts are stored in a similar side table.